# orderBy('id', 'desc') and orderBy('id', 'asc') returning same value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image: query result]
i am trying to get result query in mongodo using the orderBy "asc" and "desc" . but both of them are returning the result in same order..

db.languages.find().sort({a:1})
 db.languages.find().sort({a:-1})

Comment: a is not a field in collection! try this 
db.languages.find().sort({name :1}) db.languages.find().sort({ name : -1})

Comment: i have a table named languages. which contain two data . and i wanted to see output in descending order with respective to id but i always see result in ascending order.

Comment: did you tried above queries from my comment!?

Comment: i did try it replacing "a" with "id" still same result but when i change it to "name" it works .. can you tell me the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sort in mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

you can sort only by field names in collection. a or id is not field, 
You can try with _id or created_by also.

```
db.languages.find().sort({name :1})
db.languages.find().sort({ name : -1})
```